# connecting to local mongodb from drone.io

Tags: mongodb, automation, drone.io

mongodb is running on my local machine and i want to connect this mongodb from drone.io. but i am getting error message as below

> com.mongodb.com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException:
> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting for a server that matches
> ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
> cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017,
> type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
> socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

Can any one help on this how can i connect my local mongodb from drone.io

Comment: `Connection refused` means the operating system actively refused the connection because there was nothing listening on that port.

Comment: i checked port is open to listen, i believe issue is mongodb is running in mylocal and drone.io is not able to connect it , any idea how can i make  connection between my localhost and drone.io

Comment: If you have instructed a remote system to connect to localhost, it will be connecting to itself, not your machine.

Comment: i changed localhost to my private/LAN IP Address but still i am getting same error message

>       self.reports.initExtentReport()
E       com.mongodb.com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=172.29.1.77:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out}}]